# Count number of instances using a metaclass in Python

Tags: python, encapsulation, python-3.8, metaclass, information-hiding

I've written a *metaclass* which counts the number of instances for each of its children class.
So my *meta* has a *dict* like `{classname: number_of_instances}`.

This is the implementation:

```
class MetaCounter(type):
    
    _counter = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        cls._counter[name] = 0
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._counter[cls.__name__] += 1
        print(f'Instantiated {cls._counter[cls.__name__]} objects of class {cls}!')
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)



class Foo(metaclass=MetaCounter):
    pass


class Bar(metaclass=MetaCounter):
    pass


x = Foo()
y = Foo()
z = Foo()
a = Bar()
b = Bar()
print(MetaCounter._counter)
# {'Foo': 3, 'Bar': 2} --> OK!
print(Foo._counter)
# {'Foo': 3, 'Bar': 2} --> I'd like it printed just "3"
print(Bar._counter) 
# {'Foo': 3, 'Bar': 2} --> I'd like it printed just "2"
```

It works fine but I want to add a level of information hiding. That is, classes whom *metaclass* is **MetaCounter** should not have the counter of instances of other classes with the same meta. They should just have the information regarding the number of **their** instances.
So `MetaCounter._counter` should display the entire *dict*, but `Foo._counter` (let *Foo* be a class with *MetaCounter* as its *metaclass*) should just return the number of *Foo* instances.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried to override `__getattribute__` but it ended in messing around with the counting logic.

I've also tried to put `_counter` as attribute in the `dict` parameter of the `__new__` method, but then it became also an instance member and I didn't want so.

Comment: This kind of class-wide instance counter is almost always a bad idea in the first place. It's not thread-safe, it becomes GC-unsafe if you try to make it threadsafe, there are almost no uses for it, any uses are better handled by other techniques, and it adds unnecessary overhead when you're not using it.

Comment: On top of that, doing it with a metaclass adds metaclass conflict issues when you want to inherit from a class that uses another metaclass.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica +1 cause I agree with you, but that's just for didactic purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know enough metaclasses to say if it is a bad idea to do what you are trying but it is possible.

You can make `MetaCounter` just keep references to its "metaclassed" classes and add a specific instance counter to each one by updating the `dict` in `MetaCounter.__new__` method:

```py
class MetaCounter(type):
    _classes = []

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        dict.update(_counter=0)
        metaclassed = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
        cls._classes.append(metaclassed)
        return metaclassed
```

Each time a new `MetaCounter` class is instantiated, you increment the counter

```py
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._counter += 1
        print(f'Instantiated {cls._counter} objects of class {cls}!')
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This ensures each `MetaCounter` class owns its instance counter and does not know anything about other `MetaCounter` classes.

Then, to get all the counters, you can add a `_counters` static method to `MetaCounter`, which returns the counter for each `MetaCounter` class:

```py
    @classmethod
    def _counters(cls):
        return {klass: klass._counter for klass in cls._classes}
```

Then you are done:

```sh
print(MetaCounter._counters())  # {<class '__main__.Foo'>: 3, <class '__main__.Bar'>: 2}
print(Foo._counter)  # 3
print(Bar._counter)  # 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fine. This will add `_counter` attribute available also for instances, won't it? --> `x = Foo()     print(x._counter) --> "1"`. What if I want to keep that information available only at class level?

Comment: @dc_Bita98 why? Generally, an instance has all the information available to the class... that is sort of a central aspect of class-based OOP. You could, I suppose, create some sort of descriptor for `_counter` that prevents access when used by an instance. This is getting highly impractical though

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to make class attributes non-reachable by instances

Comment: Mine was just a thought. I'm gonna accept this answer because it solved the problem (tested now)

Comment: This is almost unretouchable - but for the fact that the `_counters` method in `MetaCounter` does  not have any reason to be a "staticmethod" - it can - and should - be a classmethod, since it does have a use the `cls` parameter .

Comment: @jsbueno hum... I actually just forgot the `@classmethod` decorator (shame :x ). So you are right, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example with the use of a **descriptor** to modify the behavior of the `_counter` attribute based on whether it's accessed by *instance* (the class) or by *class* (the metaclass in this case)

```
class descr:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = {}
        self.previous_counter_value = {}

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance:
            return self.counter[instance]
        else:
            return self.counter

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.counter[instance] = value
    

class MetaCounter(type):
    
    _counter = descr()

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
        cls._counter[new_class] = 0
        return new_class


    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._counter += 1
        print(f'Instantiated {cls._counter} objects of class {cls}!')
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```